# Hide certain rows in Excel based on value AND checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA coding. I'm trying to Hide and Unhide rows based on two criteria: (1) If a checkbox is clicked and (2) If a value on that row has a certain number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub HideRows_Revenue()
     If CheckBox1 = True Then
     BeginRow = 1
     EndRow = 100
     ChkCol = 1
     For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
          If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 1 Then
             Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
          End If
     Next RowCnt
Else
     BeginRow = 1
     EndRow = 20
     ChkCol = 1
     For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
          If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = 1 Then
               Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
          End If
     Next RowCnt
```

End Sub

Comment: What is your question? Please explain what the problem is instead of expecting us to figure this out from the code. Do you get an error? Do you see something unexpected happening?

Comment: Apologies! I'm getting a Compile Error Message: "Block If without End If"

Comment: Missing `End If` just before `End Sub`

Comment: Maybe you want to indent your code properly. Then you see the missing `End if` before the `End Sub`